# Which is faster pandas.iterrows () or UDF function?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, google-colaboratory, data-analysis

I have a doubt.
Which of these two is faster to perform? I am using ***Google Colab***. 
This way I use **iterrrow()** of *pandas* to loop through all lines.
These two that I have written are simply as an example, to understand which of the two are faster. 
In the case of ***withColumn***, how can I apply it to the randomFunction function?

This is UDF:

```
import string

def randomFunction(text):
    if (text == "Hello"):
       cnt_en += 1
    else:
       cnt_en -= 1
    return cnt_en
```

This is a loop cycle:

```
cnt_en = 0
for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
  if (text == "Hello"):
       cnt_en += 1
    else:
       cnt_en -= 1
print (cnt_en)
```

Can anyone tell me which of the two is faster?
I have a dataframe with ***2,500,000 rows***.

Comment: why you are not using withColumn() df = df.withColumn("col_name", F.col("col_name").cast(T.IntegerType())) -> This will be way faster than above two

Comment: @dsk Perfect!! But what if it's not a "standard" function like string to integer casting (or vice versa)? For example a function like the one I just added to the question above?

Answer (score 0):

For speed, you are almost always better off using vectorized functions and avoid explicit looping (looping occurs anyway, but in compiled code, not over as a Python function).  This requires some thinking and adaptation based on the functionality desired.

For example, you would transform your `randomFunction()` into:

```py
cnt_en = 2 * (df['text'] == 'Hello').sum() - df.shape[0]
```

To illustrate the speed difference:

```py
n = 2_500_000 // 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': np.random.choice('Hi Hello World'.split(), n),
})

def base(df):
    cnt_en = 0
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['text'] == "Hello"):
            cnt_en += 1
        else:
            cnt_en -= 1

    return cnt_en

def modified(df):
    return 2 * (df['text'] == 'Hello').sum() - df.shape[0]

t_base = %timeit -o base(df)
# 1.45 s ± 6.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

t_modf = %timeit -o modified(df)
# 1.7 ms ± 994 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> t_base.average // t_modf.average
855.0
```

**The speedup is over 800x**. On the full 2.5M rows, `modified()` takes 150ms on my machine.

Side note: I had to adapt your code, as neither snippet works as provided.